# How to show user inputed data into JLebel in netbeans GUI builder without reinitiating the frame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am doing a small program which is part of an project. Its like quit a prototype testing.

In the program i have one textfield, one button and a Label to show the text which will be imputed into in the text field.
(Due to low reputation i am unable to upload a PIC of the GUI.)

Here i am taking input in the text field. The text field is able to take system date as input if button "take_System_date" pressed. Then as an action of the text field, the input will be shown into the label. I am doing this using netbeans gui builder.For JLabel value set Text value i have given custom code and putted the variable "text". The source has given below.

```
    package test_custom_label_printing;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class customLebel_Printing extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String text=null;
    String initializatioDate=null;
    public customLebel_Printing(String textForConstructor, String dateForConstructor) 
    {
//     textInput();
     text=textForConstructor; 
     initializatioDate=dateForConstructor;
     initComponents();
    }
    public customLebel_Printing() 
    {
     initComponents();
    }

public void textInput()
{
     text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ur text here :");

}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//Computer generated code has not given

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        String date=jTextField1.getText();

        text=jTextField1.getText();
//        text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ur text Here( In Text Field event):");
        initComponents();   
        customLebel_Printing call = new customLebel_Printing(text,date);
        call.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();

    }                                           

    private void take_System_date_jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          

        DateFormat onlyDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        jTextField1.setText(onlyDate.format(date));
    }                                                         

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customLebel_Printing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customLebel_Printing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customLebel_Printing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customLebel_Printing.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new customLebel_Printing().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel input_jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton take_System_date_jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Program is working. But my problem is that to show the inputted text i am re-initiating the window and that my current window is closing and the same window is coming again.

I think it is not an efficient idea. As i told before i am doing this as a prototype. I will use this same concept for a project which has  a quit big window and many options on that window and re-initiating a big is not nice to look. In my project a user Id will inputted in the text field and in the label the ID's user name and address will be shown by reading values from the database.

now i want to know is there any way to do this in netbeans with out re-initiating the window. i am not understanding how to write custom code for the JPanel in netbeans GUI builder For viewing text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need add this line, if I understand well

```
private void take_System_date_jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          

    DateFormat onlyDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    jTextField1.setText(onlyDate.format(date));
    jLabel1.setText(jTextField1.getText());
}
```

Comment: yes..it is working would u please tell me how i can show text in panel which has made by GUI builder. @Ján Яabčan

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean. You cant directly show text in a JPanel. You can set text only for components which extend JTextComponent. It is for example JTextArea, JTextField, JLabel, JTextPane.... If you want to show text in JPanel, you have to add JLabel into JPanel and set text for this label(or another JTextComponent). If you use GUI Builder, just add JPanel to your JFrame and next just drag jlabel from palette and drop it into JPanel and somewhere in code call method jlabel.setText(...);